# Icons not showing on Tab Navigator with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having problems to show Icons using `createBottomTabNavigator`. I am using react-native-ionicons, and it works fine if I put any kind of Icon in the code, but is not showing on the tab bar. **I already set `showIcon: true`**.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomepageScreen';

  class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Settings!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

const BottomNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Settings: SettingsScreen,
    },
    {
      tabBarOptions: {
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        showLabel: true,
        showIcon: true
      },
    }
  );

export default createAppContainer(BottomNavigation);
```

Where HomepageScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Card, CardItem, Right, Left} from 'native-base';
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
        news: []
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Noticias',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
            <Icon style={{width: 10, height: 10, color: 'black'}} ios="ios-add" android="md-add" />
        }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        //code
      );
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the size was probably too small, and you need to put `color={tintColor}` if you're going to put `tintColor` to use

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Card, CardItem, Right, Left} from 'native-base';
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons'

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Noticias',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => {
            <Icon color={tintColor} ios="ios-add" android="md-add" />
        }
    }


    render() {
      return (
        //code
      );
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

hope it helps!